Need to combine Shopify product line_item with free discount
$data = [
                    'price_rule' => [
                        'title' => $point.' off',
                        'value_type' => 'fixed_amount',
                        'value' => -$point,
                        // 'customer_selection' => 'all',
                        "customer_selection" => "prerequisite",
                        "prerequisite_customer_ids" => [$cust_id],
                        "usage_limit" => 1,
                        'target_type' => 'line_item',
                        'target_selection' => 'all',
                        'allocation_method' => 'across',
                        'starts_at' => $formattedDateTime, 
                        'ends_at' => $expiredFormattedDateTime,
                        'entitled_shipping_lines' => [
                            'title' => 'Free Shipping' // You might need to adjust this based on your shipping method title
                        ],
                        'allocation_limit' => null
                    ]
                ];

In the above code entitled_shipping_lines is not getting combined with product discount
Many cmobinations to make this work
